# Using python SALib saltelli.sample method with boolean or discrete input parameters

Tags: python, data-modeling

I would like to use the Sobol method to run a sensitivity analysis on a complex model in python. This model includes continuous, discrete, as well as boolean input parameters.

Is it possible to use the SALib python package to perform this analysis?  Specifically, can I use the saltelli.sample method to generate quasi-random sets of input parameters when some of them don't actually have upper or lower bounds but instead only several discrete options (like 0 or 1, for instance)

Here is an example of the saltelli.sample method (which generates low-discrepancy sequences) from the SALib documentation:

```
from SALib.sample import saltelli
import numpy as np

problem = {
  'num_vars': 3, 
  'names': ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'], 
  'bounds': [[-np.pi, np.pi]]*3
}

# Generate samples
param_values = saltelli.sample(problem, 1000, calc_second_order=True)
```

My question is, how (if at all) can I use this method if my input parameters are more like this:

```
x1: continuous (so possible values could be 0, 0.01, 1.2...0.987)
x2: boolean (so possible values are 0 or 1)
x3: discrete (so possible values are 0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, or 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution posted on Github and wanted to share here for others:

Right now there is no way to (properly) sample discrete or boolean values. So I'd suggest a hack: sample a continous range and round to the nearest value you want.

If it's a boolean variable, sample on [0,1] and just round up or down. If it's discrete with N outcomes, sample on [0,N] and round to the nearest integer.

There was a blog post about this a while back:
https://waterprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/02/11/extensions-of-salib-for-more-complex-sensitivity-analyses/ (item 2 on the list)

It is a little hacky, but I think this is the more-or-less accepted way of doing things, especially if you're mixing continuous and discrete variables.

Comment: Is this still the best solution or has something more native been implemented in SALib?